# extending phaser button class not working

Tags: javascript, oop, phaser-framework

i need to extend phaser button class to create new one but there is no buttons in the stage however there is no errors in the console this is my code to extend the class

```
var GAME = GAME || {}; // game namespace 
GAME.UiButton = function(){ // game class for buttons

            Phaser.Button.call(this,game);
    };
    GAME.UiButton.prototype = Object.create(Phaser.Button.prototype);
    GAME.UiButton.constructor = Phaser.Button;
    //

    game.state.start("preloader");
```

then when i create new object there is no buttons in screen

```
var playButton = new GAME.UiButton(game,0,0,"button");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor doesn't have any parameters.

```
GAME.UiButton = function(game, x, y, key, etc...){ 
    Phaser.Button.call(this, game, x, y, key, etc...);
};
```

or

```
GAME.UiButton = function(){ 
    Phaser.Button.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

and you never add the button to the game.

```
game.add.existing(playButton)
```

[**DEMO**](http://phaser.io/sandbox/edit/PoOWsnVV)